# Is it possible to set git clone to always use --reference?

Tags: git

I'd like to set git clone to always use --reference /path/to/mirror. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe so. Why would you want that anyway? Repositories for different projects will always be different. What if you explained what you wanted to achieve instead?

Comment: I would find an answer to this question extremely useful.  To speed up cloning of repos when creating new workspaces across many users on a single machine, it is useful to be able to set up a git cache directory that can be referenced by any repo to avoid the space and time it takes to copy every time you clone.  See tools such as `git cache` that help in setting up the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.
You could define a specific alias maybe, but you need to pass your /path/to/mirror as a parameter anyway.
And that path to mirror should be a *local* path to a bare repo (as described in "[Reference (cache) repositories to speed up clones: `git clone --reference`](http://randyfay.com/node/93)".

The [`git clone` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-clone) does mention some issue with that approach:

> this is a possibly dangerous operation; do not use it unless you understand what it does.
>   If you clone your repository using this option and then delete branches (or use any other git command that makes any existing commit unreferenced) in the source repository, some objects may become unreferenced (or dangling).
>   These objects may be removed by normal git operations (such as `git commit`) which automatically call `git gc --auto`.
>   If these objects are removed and were referenced by the cloned repository, then the cloned repository will become corrupt.

As an alternative, you also got the [`git alternates` project](http://dustin.github.com/2008/12/30/git-alternates.html) as a dedicated (custom) command for managing the same thing.